# Transparent status bar

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve a seamlessly transparent status bar on my app, so far this is what I have achieved:

[image]

As you can see a) the status bar is not really fully transparent and b) the toolbar is cut off.

This is my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_appbar"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    (...)
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

styles-v21.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/ChipStyle</item>


    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>

    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/ChipStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

</style>
```

I've tried all combinations of fitSystemWindows, I really dont understand what this is doing.

Comment: did you call setSupportActionBar(toolbar)?

Comment: yes i am calling that

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit not yet --- I want to see if there is a less hacky way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a hacky way.. but probably will help you..

What you can do is calculate height of `StatusBar` and add padding top of `toolbar` as much as height of `StatusBar`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        toolbar.setPadding(0,getStatusBarHeight(context),0,0);
}
```

And to get Height of `StatusBar`

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight(final Context context) {
    final Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    else
        return (int) Math.ceil((VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M ? 24 : 25) * resources.getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

**EDIT :**

you need to set height of your `ToolBar` to `wrap_content`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

OUT-PUT :

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Happy Coding.

Comment: this shifts down the content from the topbar, but the topbar remains same size and thus the content is overlapping :(

Comment: what is value of `android:fitsSystemWindows`? true or false? can you attach ss?

Comment: You have to give toolbar height `wrap_content` and `android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171004/discussion-between-gabriel-sanmartin-and-v-rund-puro-hit).

Comment: That did indeed fix it, thanks. I just wonder if there is a more stantard way of doing it --- but I can live with this.

Comment: I Tried to find it for weeks but could't find it :D but i'm sure there will be way for doing that without hack.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your Activity onCreate()

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); 
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `Toolbar` and also `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>` from the style. `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` causes things to be drawn under the status bar.

Comment: I get same result with this

Comment: What is the root layout which has the appbar? Post that part also.

Comment: I had posted it but apparently StackOverflow hid it for some reason. It is visible now. Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the root LinearLayout? Remove from the Toolbar and add to root.

Comment: Ok. Replace the root layout with CoordinatorLayout. AppbarLayout is designed to work with CoordinatorLayout. It can cause errors if used inside other root layouts.

Comment: Changed to Coordinator --- same results :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170991/discussion-between-harikumar-alangode-and-gabriel-sanmartin).